# IComparable implementation for list of students and linq Max and Min methods

Tags: c#, linq

I have implemented the `IComparable` interface on my `Student` class, and I am trying to get the min and max **Age** of the students in the list. I am getting max value correctly but not min value. What am I missing in the code?

I am not sure whether Linq **MAX** and **MIN** methods gives correct results on the list of class which implements `IComparable`. When I run the below code I get Max Age = 31, Min age = 20 (**but it should be 17**)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<Student> stuList = new List<Student>(){
            new Student(){StudentID=1,StudentName="Mike",Age=20},
            new Student(){StudentID=2,StudentName="Nick",Age=24},
            new Student(){StudentID=3,StudentName="Mary",Age=21},
            new Student(){StudentID=4,StudentName="John",Age=17},
            new Student(){StudentID=5,StudentName="Dave",Age=29},
            new Student(){StudentID=6,StudentName="Don",Age=31}     
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Total Students: "+stuList.Count());
        var maxstud = stuList.Max();
        var minstud = stuList.Min();
        Console.WriteLine("Max Age: "+ maxstud.Age);
        Console.WriteLine("Min Age: "+ minstud.Age);
    }
}   

public class Student : IComparable<Student>
{
    public int StudentID {get;set;}
    public string StudentName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}

    public int CompareTo(Student other)
    {
        if(this.Age >= other.Age)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

If I use lambda exp I am getting correct min value:

```
Console.WriteLine("Min Age: "+ stuList.Min(s=>s.Age));// Min age =17
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `CompareTo` implementation is not correct, it should return a value lower than `0` in certain cases.

> The implementation of the `CompareTo(T)` method must return an `Int32`
>   that has one of three values, as shown in the following table.
>
> **Less than zero**    This object precedes the object specified by the `CompareTo` method in the sort order.
>
> **Zero**    This current instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as the object specified by the `CompareTo` method argument.
>
> **Greater than zero**    This current instance follows the object specified by the `CompareTo` method argument in the sort order.

The easiest way to do that would be to do this:

```
public int CompareTo(Student other)
{
    return this.Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use the CompareTo already implemented by the framework on the Age property.

```
public int CompareTo(Student other)
{
    return this.Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
}
```